# Problems with Encryption API on Honeycomb/Motorola Xoom

Tags: android, motorola, android-3.0-honeycomb, motorola-droid

I want to encrypt my tablet using device administrator, but when I call method `setStorageEncryption` from `DevicePolicyManager` class, encryption state does not change. This method returns `ENCRYPTION_STATUS_ACTIVE`, but when I call `getStorageEncryptionStatus` I get `ENCRYPTION_STATUS_INACTIVE`.

In ApiDemos there is a `SampleDeviceAdmin` class **(API Demos/App/Device Admin)**. There are 3 buttons: `Enable Encryption, Disable Encryption and Activate Encryption`. I understand the purpose of last one (it manually starts an activity). But how are the first two buttons supposed to work? Because it appears they don't have any impact for device encryption.

If anybody has tried this API I'll be very grateful for any help!